# rewrite index.php?p=page to page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My urls currently look like this: http://www.morrisononline.com/index.php?p=contact
I would like to rewrite them to http://www.morrisononline.com/contact
The content for (in this case) contact comes from the directory /pages/ (www.morrisononline.com/pages/contact.php)

I have tried the following in the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have also tried other combinations too (I'm not very good at this and trying lots of suggestions from other forum posts etc) but nothing has any effect. No error messages and no rewrites either. Did I do it wrong or could there be another command before that, that overrides this? 
Do I have to refresh some cache or restart the server for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `AllowOverride All` or at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your site's config for the site's document root. And make sure the htaccess file is in the document root, is readable by everyone. If it's still not working, make sure that you've got `AccessFileName` set to `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried all these options but all of them cause a 500 server error. The .htaccess file is set to 644 as far as rights goes.